# $T(O)$ is not open where $T$ is an inclusion map

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that $T(O)$ is not open in $Y$ where $T:X\to Y$ is a linear function given by $Tx = x$, and $$
X = Y = \{x = (x_1,x_2,\dots), \sum_i |x_i|<\infty\}$$
is normed linear spaces with norms $\|x\|_X = \sum_i|x_i|$ and $\|x\|_Y = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|$ (they are not Banach).

I want to show that there exists a point $y\in T(O)$ such that $B_{Y}(y; r)\not\subset T(O)$ where $O = \{x\in X : \|x\|_X < 1\}$

Here I cannot proceed anymore. Any helps will be more than welcome.

Comment: Don't we need to know what "O" is?   Is it just some arbitrary open set in X?

Comment: @HallsofIvy Sorry, I edited the question

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I edited the question and what I want to show is that $T(O)$ is not open in $Y$ where $O$ is an open ball

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice that the norms are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we want to show that the set $O=\{x\in X: x=(x_n), \sum_n|x_n|<1\}$ is not open with respect to the supremum norm. Consider the point $x=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0,0,\dots)$. Then $x\in O$. We will show that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x$ in the supremum norm but $x_n\not\in O$ for all $n$. We set

$$x_n=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,0,\dots) $$

where we have $1/n$ appearing $n$ times. Note that $1/3+1/3+1/n+\dots+1/n+0+0+0+\dots=1/3+1/3+1>1$, so $x_n\not\in O$ for any $n$. On the other hand,
$$\|x_n-x\|_\infty=\frac{1}{n}\to0.$$

What we have shown is that the open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)$ with respect to the supremum norm is not a subset of $O$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, so $O$ is not open with respect to the supremum norm.

Comment: What does it have to do with the operator $T:X\to Y$? I don't see it directly

Comment: @MathislikeFriday the operator $T$ is the identity operator

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I was wondering why $1/3+1/3+1/n+⋯+1/n+0+0+0+⋯=1/3+1/3+1$ holds? Why does $1/n$ go to 1? Since later on you said that $∥xn−x∥∞=1/n→0$ , so here $1/n$ goes to $0$... I think I'm misunderstanding something, could you maybe explain?

Comment: @Math420 it does not "go to" 1, i am adding $1/n$ $n$ times, so $1/n+\dots+1/n=n\cdot 1/n=1$.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Ofcourse... I see it now. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Math420 Glad I could help